# How to model java classes representing a recursive grammar?

Tags: java, recursion, grammar, context-free-grammar

I have this simple recursive grammar:

```
T --> a | aT
```

Are there some best practices?

Anyway, my idea is pretty simple but I am not sure if it is a good one.

```
public abstract class Tclass {

}

public class Tclass1 extends Tclass{

private String a;

}

public class Tclass2 extends Tclass{

private String a;
private Tclass t;

}
```

Comment: There is a best practice: use ANTLR for parsers. If you want to code your own then learn how ANTLR works for start.

Comment: The fitting model highly depends on your requirements. What should your program do? What are you doing with the grammar? How are you creating/parsing the grammar? and so on... The best practice is to start with some implementation that works in the context and refactor it if it doesn't fit anymore. It's impossible to tell from the information you've given us and even if you did it'll be too complex. I'm voting close as too broad.

Comment: Ummm ... read this before you ask about "best practice"!   http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27

Comment: @Zefick - ANTLR is very cool, but referring to it as a "best practice" is entirely a matter of opinion. In addition, sometimes students are required to write their recursive descent parser.

Comment: Well to be precise, I already use ANTLR. It is very useful to detect the rules, but in my program I also need to build a parallel structure for some purpose. The question was not meant how to traverse the recursive tree, since ANTLR does it, but how to model this structure to store data.